# How to join dataframes to one Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with columns:

```
AGE NAME COUNTRY EMAIL
19   Ola  usa     olg@gmail.com
PHONE AGE COUNTY
+983   18  usa
```

How to join into one dataframe by the same columns:

```
AGE NAME COUNTRY EMAIL         PHONE
19  Ola  usa     olg@gmail.com 
18       usa                 +983
```

I tried to iterate all columns from one frame and compare with column from another. (loop in loop). but seems it is wrong way.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html

Simply put:

`result = pd.concat(frames)`